# Ruby JSON parse method has a instance variable quirk

Tags: ruby, json

So basically, sometimes when I use `JSON.parse` and set the returned value to a variable, later in my app that variable will turn out to be `NilClass`.

*What?*

Take a look at this: Doing

```
require 'rest-client'

class Foo
  attr_reader :response
  @response = JSON.parse RestClient.get "http://path/to/api/?params"
end

foo = Foo.new
puts foo.response.class
```

prints out `NilClass`. Funky, right? On top of that, this means that all of the data within `@response` is rendered useless, as its inaccessible being of `NilClass`. Yet, just printing out `foo.response` will actually give all of data. Why is that? I made a workaround where within my method I set the Hash to a local variable and return that instead of a instance variable, but that's rather inconvenient.

Comment: You're not setting `@response` on any instance of `Foo`, but on the class `Foo` itself.  What is your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code given above, the `@response` is not a instance variable, it's a **class instance variable**.

```
foo.instance_variables   # => []
Foo.instance_variables   # => [:@response]
```

You can change the code like this

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :response

  def initialize
    @response = JSON.parse RestClient.get "http://path/to/api/?params"
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, so what if I change the class to instead be a module? Will the same problem still persist?

Comment: @dude0faw3 What's your actual *purpose*? Why do you want it to be a module? How will you be trying to *use* this functionality?

Comment: @dude0faw3 If you change the class to a module, then you cannot initiate a instance, but you can use the module methods or mixin the module to some other class. Depending on how you want to use it in your code.